# How to have a function calculate multiple rows of distance using latitude and longitude in MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is the function I made:

```
create function Route_Distance (lat1 FLOAT, lng1 FLOAT, lat2 FLOAT, lng2 FLOAT)
   returns float
   deterministic
   begin 
       return 6371 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((lat1-lat2)*pi()/180 /2), 2)
 + COS(lat1 * pi()/180) * COS(lat2 * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((lng1 - lng2)
 * pi()/180 /2), 2)));

 End
```

This is the table I need to calculate the distance from called routes_distance:

```
----------------------------------------------------
    lat1     |    lng1     |    lat2     | lng2     |
----------------------------------------------------
   59.914    |   -61.111   |      43.211 | 54.231
----------------------------------------------------
```

So the function I use is this:

```
 select route_distance(lat1,lng1,lat2, lng1)
from routes_distance;
```

Why is it I get a row of zeros for my result? The table is much longer, I have only shown the first row. I want to calculate all rows using this function.

Comment: Your code works fine in [this DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c4d7a8a66d655c6c19daf90bea1ec00).

Comment: I see it works for me too if I type in the values manually. But I have about 1000 latitude and longitude values. How would I go about calculating the distances in that case?

Comment: I don't understand why 1000 would be any different than 1

Comment: I think there's something wrong with my table as I created the table using JOIN (from two different tables). When I run it through the function I get null values. Whereas, if I create the table from scratch without using JOIN and manually create the fields and type in the latitude and longitude values it works in that case. It's pretty strange.

Comment: *something wrong with my table as I created the table using JOIN (from two different tables). When I run it through the function I get null values.* All? Some? Edit the fiddle. Add the structure of the table. Dump from your DB and add into the fiddle 10-12 records which gives NULLs. Give the link to edited fiddle. *from two different tables* Maybe something wrong with this process? Create a fiddle with source tables, some data and query which transfers data into the table in question.